# Open Perspective programmatically

Tags: eclipse-rcp, e4

I am trying to provide a command/ handler to switch to a specific Perspective.

I came up with the following class:

```
public class OpenPerspectiveHandler {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(OpenPerspectiveHandler.class);
    @Inject
    private MApplication application;
    @Inject
    private EModelService modelService;
    @Inject
    private EPartService partService;
    private final String perspectiveId;

    public OpenPerspectiveHandler(String perspectiveId) {
        super();
        this.perspectiveId = perspectiveId;
    }

    public void changePerspective(String perspectiveId) {

        Optional<MPerspective> perspective = findPerspective();
        if(perspective.isPresent()) {
            partService.switchPerspective(perspective.get());
        } else {
            logger.debug("Perspective not found (" + perspectiveId + ")");
        }
    }

    @Execute
    public void execute() {

        changePerspective(perspectiveId);
    }

    private Optional<MPerspective> findPerspective() {

        MUIElement element = modelService.find(perspectiveId, application);
        if(element instanceof MPerspective) {
            return Optional.of((MPerspective)element);
        } else {
            logger.debug("Wrong type " + element);
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return "OpenPerspectiveHandler [application=" + application + ", modelService=" + modelService + ", partService=" + partService + ", perspectiveId=" + perspectiveId + "]";
    }
}
```

Interestingly, this works only once. A workaround is to cache `MPerspective` once it was found and not to use `modelService.find(perspectiveId, application)` again.

Why does it work only once? `modelService.find(perspectiveId, application)` returns `null` after the first execution.

**EDIT:**

Another approach (as suggested by greg-449) is the following:

```
public class OpenPerspectiveHandler {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(OpenPerspectiveHandler.class);
    private final String perspectiveId;

    public OpenPerspectiveHandler(String perspectiveId) {
        super();
        this.perspectiveId = perspectiveId;
    }

    @Execute
    public void changePerspective(MApplication application, EModelService modelService, EPartService partService) {

        Optional<MPerspective> perspective = findPerspective(application, modelService);
        if(perspective.isPresent()) {
            partService.switchPerspective(perspective.get());
        } else {
            logger.debug("Perspective not found (" + perspectiveId + ")");
        }
    }

    private Optional<MPerspective> findPerspective(MApplication application, EModelService modelService) {

        MUIElement element = modelService.find(perspectiveId, application);
        if(element instanceof MPerspective) {
            return Optional.of((MPerspective)element);
        } else {
            logger.debug("Wrong type " + element);
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

But this approach also changes the perspective only once. `modelService.find(perspectiveId, application);` returns `null` after the first execution.

Comment: Well what part of this is not working the second time? For example is the model service find working? Note that it is best **not** to use field injection in a handler, always inject everything as arguments to the @Execute method. Things like the part service can change depending on the context.

Comment: `modelService.find(perspectiveId, application)` will return `null` after the first execution.

Comment: Thanks for the hint on injecting to the @Execute method. Please see updated question.

Comment: 'No active window' means you are using the EPartService for the application (rather than a window) which requires there to be an active window. If you are running this during startup you need to do this in the App Startup Complete event when the window will be available.

Comment: I am not calling the handler during startup, at least not intentionally. I have a `Menu` and a `HandledMenuContribution` defined in a `fragment.e4xmi` to execute the handler.

Comment: Do you have a Dialog open or something like that? There is no active window when a dialog is open. You can bypass this problem by using the model service to find your main window and getting the EPartService from the MWindow's context rather than injecting the service.

Comment: Nothing like that. The exception occurs during startup, before or right after the main window appears. The result is "greyed out" menu entries.

Comment: "You can bypass this problem by using the model service to find your main window and getting the EPartService from the MWindow's context rather than injecting the service. " How do I do that?

Comment: It is strange that this code is executed before I select the corresponding menu entry. According to the stack trace, the @Execute method is called by the InjectorImpl.inject().

Comment: Removing the @Inject annotation solves the Exception-problem.

Comment: The @Inject is causing the method to be injected when the handler is constructed, not what you want.

Comment: The "works only once" problem is still there, also when I inject in the @Execute method

Answer (score 0):

The `EPartService` varies depending on the context that the handler runs in. In some cases you get the Application part service which only works if there is an active window.

You can get the part service for that window using something like:

```java
MWindow window = (MWindow)modelService.find("top window id", application);

IEclipseContext windowContext = window.getContext();

EPartService windowPartService = windowContext.get(EPartService.class);
```

Comment: Same problem using this approach. The windowPartService is not the problem, the `MPerspective` object is `null` (`modelService.find(perspectiveId, application);`).

Comment: Maybe it is related to this `!MESSAGE Perspective with name 'Identify' and id '[..].ui.perspective.identify' has been made into a local copy`

Comment: Is this just e4 or is it mixed with e3 components - because that message sounds like [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=489816)

Comment: We use some Wizards and Preferences pages defined in `plugin.xml`. So I guess it is mixed. How can I tell for sure?

Comment: If you are using any org.eclipse.ui.xxx plugins or your application is **not** org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application it is mixed. JFace code is OK for e4

Comment: Thanks a lot! So it's mixed. If it is this bug, what would be the best workaround?

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution for this? I'm having the exact same issue with it not finding it when executing the method a second time.