# Perspective is null after the first call

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

Recently I've been porting across all perspectives and views from RCP 3 to RCP 4. I would now like to switch between perspectives in my RCP 4 application.

After changing to a perspective the first time this is output.

```
!MESSAGE Perspective with name 'perspective_label' and id 'PerspectiveName' has been made into a local copy
```

To switch perspective I use this

```
@Inject
private static MApplication app;

@Inject 
private static EPartService partService;

@Inject 
private static EModelService modelService;

@Inject
private static MWindow window;

private static void switchPerspective(final String id)
{   
    final Optional<MPerspective> perspective = PerspectiveSwitcherToolbar.findPerspective(id);
    if(perspective.isPresent()) 
    {
        partService.switchPerspective(perspective.get());
    } 
    else 
    {
        System.out.println("Perspective not found");
    }
}

private static Optional<MPerspective> findPerspective(final String perspectiveId) 
{
    final MUIElement element = modelService.find(perspectiveId, app);
    if(element instanceof MPerspective)
    {
        perspectiveIdsToElement.put(perspectiveId, (MPerspective) element);
        return Optional.of((MPerspective)element);
    } 

    System.out.println("Wrong type " + element);
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

On the first call to switch perspective it changes correctly. On the second call `findPerspective` returns `empty()`.

I found this question which seems to be about the exact same issue but doesn't solve the problem.

[Open Perspective programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44927967/open-perspective-programmatically/44929442#44929442)

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'made in to a local copy' message comes from `WorkbenchPage` part of the 3.x compatibilty mode code. It is trying to find the perspective in the 3.x perspectives list and failing (because you created it using e4 APIs).

It looks like you really can't use the e4 perspective APIs easily while you still have 3.x compatability mode code.

Comment: I'd like to move away from cmpatability mode really. The only things we are stuck with for now are the 3.x services but the rest should be able to transfer across. 
I'll try finding where this 3.x code is as it shouldn't be being called any more.

Comment: Can you really move from compatability mode? That means dropping all `org.eclipse.ui.xxxx` plugins and also things like `IFile`. Most existing 3.x code is very hard to move to pure e4.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure. I've managed to shift all views and perspectives over successfully (besides a few small issues). It's the menu contributions and services that I still need to do.

Comment: Is there any way I can deal with this at the moment? If I can change perspectives successfully then everything else will work for the moment.

Comment: Sorry but I don't know. I don't use perspectives or mixed e4/3.x code.

Comment: I decided to change to a pure e4 application. This has now removed this message.